# How to Output a EventListener Result to a Variable?

Tags: javascript, event-listener

Im trying to create a script that wen i click in a movie on a website, it extracts is name and open the trailer on youtube.

```
list.addEventListener('click', function(evt){
    console.log(evt.target.innerHTML);
});

window.open("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query="+text+" Trailer");
```

I need to output that result to te variable "text", i tried many thing but still not working.

**The console.log output correctely the name of the movie i click..**

Comment: Move the `window.open` inside the event listener.

Answer (score 1):

Extending [@redneb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6776093/redneb)'s answer

```
list.addEventListener('click', function(evt){
    window.open("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query="+evt.target.innerHTML+" Trailer");
});
```